# Typescript create interface definition from Object

Tags: typescript

Suppose I have the following definitions:

```
export enum Category {
  car = 'car',
  truck = 'truck',
}

export interface IProperty {
  propertyName: string,
  propertyLabel: string,
  propertyType: 'string' | 'number',
}

export interface CategoryDefinition {
  category: Category,
  label: string,
  properties: IProperty[]
}
```

and then have definitions like that:

```
export class Definitions {

  public static get car(): CategoryDefinition {
    return {
      category: Category.car,
      label: "Car",
      properties: [
        {
          propertyName: 'weight',
          propertyLabel: 'Weight',
          propertyType: 'number'
        },
        {
          propertyName: 'color',
          propertyLabel: 'Color',
          propertyType: 'string'
        }
      ],
    };
  }

  public static get truck(): CategoryDefinition {
    return {
      category: Category.truck,
      label: "Truck",
      properties: [
        {
          propertyName: 'payload',
          propertyLabel: 'Payload',
          propertyType: 'number'
        },
        {
          propertyName: 'axles',
          propertyLabel: 'Axles',
          propertyType: 'number'
        }
      ],
    };
  }
}
```

And now, I would like to generate interfaces from this definition, which should result in this:

```
export interface Car {
  weight: number,
  color: string
}

export interface Truck{
  payload: number,
  axles: number
}
```

Ideally done someway like:

```
export interface Car = createInterface('Car', Definitions.car.properties);
export interface Truck = createInterface('Truck', Definitions.truck.properties);
```

Reason being that I have to deal with about 30-40 of those definitions. I can of course define their interface on their own (API responses), but then I would have to re-define their properties for Ui display, and this would be error-prone.
This way I would only have to define their properties and could generate their corresponding interface.

I have found [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45771307/typescript-dynamically-create-interface) that maybe hint in the right direction, however I feel that it's not quite the same and I could not get it to work.

The Definitions would be fixed (i.e. not dynamically changed/updated), if that helps.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Does this address your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52097800/typescript-create-interface-based-on-object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably make the definition types readonly (as you shouldn't need to change these at runtime):

```
export interface IProperty {
  readonly propertyName: string,
  readonly propertyLabel: string,
  readonly propertyType: 'string' | 'number',
}

export interface CategoryDefinition {
  readonly category: Category,
  readonly label: string,
  readonly properties: readonly IProperty[]
}
```

And another change needed is to use `as const satisfies CategoryDefinition` instead of annotating the return type to be `CategoryDefinition`. This "preserves" the values while still making sure it is of type `CategoryDefinition`.

```
export class Definitions {
  public static get car() {
    return {
      category: Category.car,
      label: "Car",
      properties: [
        {
          propertyName: 'weight',
          propertyLabel: 'Weight',
          propertyType: 'number'
        },
        {
          propertyName: 'color',
          propertyLabel: 'Color',
          propertyType: 'string'
        }
      ],
    } as const satisfies CategoryDefinition;
  }

  public static get truck() {
    return {
      category: Category.truck,
      label: "Truck",
      properties: [
        {
          propertyName: 'payload',
          propertyLabel: 'Payload',
          propertyType: 'number'
        },
        {
          propertyName: 'axles',
          propertyLabel: 'Axles',
          propertyType: 'number'
        }
      ],
    } as const satisfies CategoryDefinition;
  }
}
```

Then we need to define a type that maps the property types to their actual types:

```
type TypeMap = {
    string: string;
    number: number;
    // etc ...
};
```

Finally, we can map over the definition properties and retrieve the right type for each field:

```
type FromDefinition<D extends CategoryDefinition> = {
    [T in D["properties"][number] as T["propertyName"]]: TypeMap[T["propertyType"]];
};

type Car = FromDefinition<typeof Definitions["car"]>;
//   ^? { weight: number; color: string }
type Truck = FromDefinition<typeof Definitions["truck"]>;
//   ^? { payload: number; axles: number }
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mp8d6m)

---

Does your Definitions class really need to be a class? It could just be:

```
const Definitions = {
    car: { ... },
    truck: { ... },
} as const satisfies Record<string, CategoryDefinition>;
```

and that'd be simpler to read and maintain.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, it only works when using the "satisfies" keyword (and I cannot use that yet, as Angular does not support TS4.9 atm). Why is that? No way around that?

Comment: @Hafnernuss The use of `satisfies` here is to make sure the returned value matches the `CategoryDefinition` type. You don't need it here but it's just a check to make sure the returned value is valid. That's why I also suggested using an object instead of a class for `Definitions`. Then you could have a wrapper function to validate the given object.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work (correctly) without `satisfies`, as somehow the type information is lost:  `type Car = { [x:string]: string | number }`

Comment: @Hafnernuss Did you remove the `as const` as well? That's the part that makes everything readonly so TS can use the strings as literals.

Comment: you are right, the `as const` does the trick. But why do I have to remove the return annotation.
Even when using an object instead of a class, makes no difference.

Comment: @Hafnernuss If you use a return annotation, you override and lose the values that you are returning. It widens the type and it becomes useless.

Comment: I wanted to add something here, because it wasn't clear to me why I loose something with my annoations: The definitions are *not* of type `CategoryDefinition`, they are there "own" type, they are only based on `CategoryDefinition`.

Comment: @Hafnernuss It's the same as `const x: string = "hello"`. The type of `x` is now `string`, where as if you had removed the type annotation, the type would be `"hello"`. This is called "type widening".

Comment: exactly, and I wasn't aware of that. It seemse I really underestimated what the typesystem of Typescript can actually do...

Comment: How would I extend the resulting type with an additional property (`category`)? using `type Car = FromDefinition<typeof Definitions["car"]> & BaseInterface` seems not to work. I tried to extend `FromDefinition` to use an additional property from `CategoryDefinition`, could not get that to work either :/

Comment: @Hafnernuss What do you mean by that? Maybe you should ask another question on Stack Overflow instead of the comments under this post?

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to create custom types for this, which would take a bit of work (usually it's recommended to use a third-party library like [Zod](https://github.com/colinhacks/zod) to define a "schema" for your types that you also want to access in TypeScript. But, I'll see if I can come up with some types that work for your use case if you don't want to use a third-party library.

[Here's a working playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMIEMbAObQCecA3gFBxwDGWUcAvHAOQ1RMA0FcMUyVA1g2Y8+-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-QE8jKOonV8iAuAAH44GEuA5N9RT2L9IwVNANTHkDSJpkyXT0mmAy4GQRB+EQCABU6KRfCMGo6EYfCYEI1CSJ84AIFUJ56JQ95nE7Qd+EuMK4AHUQhEC4L3lC-0Iqil4iI+eLRHOIA)

There are a few things you need to tweak with your definitions (which vera explains in the other answer), but here's the "magic" type I came up with:

```
type TypeMap = {
  string: string,
  number: number,
}

export type GetDefinitionType<D extends CategoryDefinition> = {
  [Property in D['properties'][number] as Property['propertyName']]:
  TypeMap[Property['propertyType']]
}
```

What it does is loops over all the properties and then "maps" the stringified type to the actual TypeScript type using the `TypeMap` type ("string" -> `string`, "number" to `number`) (credit to vera for this idea)

The problem is, as your types get more complex, you'd need to maintain a mapping of these values yourself, which is why third-party libraries like zod exist; to handle these value -> type mappings for you (which I recommend using).