# TypeScript Extend a dynamically generated type by an additional property

Tags: typescript

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75031030/typescript-create-interface-definition-from-object/75033357?noredirect=1#comment132461734_75033357) question, I have implemented my custom types:

```js
export enum Category {
  car = 'car',
  truck = 'truck',
}

export interface Property {
  readonly name: string,
  readonly label: string,
  readonly type: 'number' | 'string',
}


export interface CategoryDefinition {
  readonly category: Category,
  readonly label: string,
  readonly properties: readonly Property[]
}

type TypeMap = {
  string: string;
  number: number;
};

type FromDefinition<D extends CategoryDefinition> = {
  [T in D['properties'][number] as T['name']]: TypeMap[T['type']];
};
```

For this (roughly):

```js
const car = {
      category: Category.car,
      label: 'Car',
      properties: [
      {
        name: 'weight',
        label: 'Weight',
        type: 'number',
      }
    ],
} as const satisfies CategoryDefinition; 

export type Car = FromDefinition<typeof car>;
```

correctly creates

```js
type Car = {
    weight: number;
}
```

Let's say, I would have to expand this type, so that it includes the category, looking like that:

```js
type Car = {
    category: 'car';
    weight: number;
}
```

The closest I could come up with, is this:

```js
export type CategoryExtension= {
  category: Category
};

type FromDefinition<D extends CategoryDefinition> = {
  [T in D['properties'][number] as T['name']]: TypeMap[T['type']];
} & CategoryExtension; // <----

export type Car = FromDefinition<typeof car>;
```

which kind of results in what I want, but looks odd:

```js
type Car = {
    height: number;
} & CategoryExtension // <----
```

How can I create the following?:

```js
type Car = {
    height: number;
    category: 'car' // or Category
}
```

Comment: So it's just a problem with *displaying* the correct types?

Comment: I do not think so, since I can leave out the `category` when creating an object with this type. But it doesn't complain if I add it, either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally this is done by making TS infer the result and a homomorphic mapped type:

```
type FromDefinition<D extends CategoryDefinition> = ({
  [T in D['properties'][number] as T['name']]: TypeMap[T['type']];
} & CategoryExtension) extends infer O ? { [K in keyof O]: O[K] } : never;
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: apparently, it really _is_ only a display issue. Thanks, I will have to read up on those things as well then.